# How to get the index of specified row without Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, indexing

Is there a way to get the index of a row in a set of rows without Pandas?
I have datetime values on the first column and I would like to address a specified day to make computations.

[image]

Comment: yes just put the rows into a dictionary keyed by date, values ought to be lists unless you are guaranteed 1 row per date.  then refer to the row by date.  you'll get better results if you paste in some sample data along with whatever code you've tried so far.  welcome aboard.

Comment: Can you post sample data and the code so that we will help.