# Delete rows before and after certain dates

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, timedelta

I have multiple timeseries, basically I established the first day of trading and the last one, I have in my database dates that I don't need (for now) and I need a code to delete those rows.
I tried with:

```
while x < len(database):
   if database[x][0] > last_day_trading:
      del database[x]
   x += 1
```

(database[x][0] is the series of dates)

I get list index out of range, maybe because every time I delete a row there is a problem with the length of the database. So the question is: what can I put instead of "len(database)"?

[image: this is how the database looks like]

Comment: I don't know how your database looks like(maybe add an example) but if you think that is your problem you can save all the row in a list and just delete them after you while loop

Comment: Also please put the code in the code sample. It's the curly brackets symbol. Your code is in blockquote which makes it hard to read.

Comment: it seems like while you *can* [do all of this in pure Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67173399/10197418), for the learning experience, there are better tools for the job. the pandas package for example.